Please explain me how many centroid of quadrilateral are possible and their respective properties?
I came across three different explanations for the centroid of a quadrilateral online:
1] Many people, by default, explain the centroid as forming two triangles along one diagonal, assuming two triangles and passing a line through their respective centroids, and similarly constructing the same line for another diagonal. The intersection of these lines gives the centroid of the quadrilateral.
2] On the other hand, I read that joining the midpoints of opposite sides with lines will give the centroid of the quadrilateral at their intersection.
3] I also saw some people explain that the centroid of a quadrilateral is essentially the center of mass of the area, assuming each point in the area has a uniformly distributed density.
1)Could someone please explain these three points and provide the default definition of the centroid of a quadrilateral?
2)How these points behave in Euclidean geometry?

1 and 3 are equivalent (I can add an answer if you want), but you can see that 2 isn’t equivalent to the others. For a simple example, consider an isosceles trapezium: 2 would give you a point at half the height, but 1 and 3 give you a point closer to the larger of the two parallel sides.

And to amplify Pranay's remark (because it took a moment for me to get it): assuming the parallel edge are horizonyal, the line between the centers of the sloping sides divides the area into a 'narrow' piece and a 'wide' piece, each of which has the same height, so the wide one weighs more than the narrow one, hence the center of mass cannot lie along that line.

So @Pranay , in complex numbers, I have learned that centroid of triangle is $({Z_{1}+Z_{2}+Z_{3}})/{3}$ but if we try to do same with quadrilateral then centroid formula become  $({Z_{1}+Z_{2}+Z_{3}+Z_{4}})/{4}$ which gives the construction of centroid discussed in [2] , but I don't know what will be complex numbers formula for 1,3 which is claiming to equal by you...., if you shows using complex numbers that point(1) = point (3) and not equal to point(2) then it will be very helpful for me. Thank you

The problem is that in a triangle the centroid of the vertices is the same as the centroid of the area. In a quadrilateral they are different: definition 2 gives the centroid of vertices, while 1 and 3 give the centroid of the area.

@Intelligentipauca Are there other types of centroids in a quadrilateral besides the 'centroid of area' (center of mass) and 'centroid of vertices' (geometric centroid)?

@Intelligenci pauca Very good and short explanation.

One could also consider the centroid of the sides, which is in general different from the others. Note that even in a triangle the centroid of the sides is not the same as the centroid of vertices and area.

@Intelligentipauca , so centroid will be nothing but a midpoint? So Centroid of quadrilateral have only three form:- 1) Aerial centroid, 2)Vector centroid, 3)Sides centroid. Am i correct?

I've never heard of other kinds of centroid, for a polygon. But I don't understand your remark "centroid will be nothing but a midpoint": a centroid is the averaged position of all the points in the figure, if you change the figure the centroid (in general) will change.
